# Programmatically add an alias to the Dock in OS X

Tags: macos, alias, dock

I know it is not recommended, but is it possible? The only references I can find relate to updating com.apple.preferences.plist but those changes will not take effect until the next time the Desktop is restarted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just restart the Dock after having changed its contents:

```
killall -HUP Dock
```